# React state variable returns to its initial value when socket io event is triggered from the server

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-hooks, socket.io

I have the following code of which is a part of a simple React+Flask+socketio chat application:

```
const ip=window.location.hostname
const socket = io("http://"+ip+":5000");
export default function Homepage() 
{

  const currUser=useSelector(state=>state.authReducer).loggedInUser
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([])
  const [selectedChatID, setSelectedChatID] = useState("")
  const [selectedChatIndex, setSelectedChatIndex] = useState(-1)

  const getChatsDataFromDB = async() => 
  {
    let chats = await messagesSVR.getMessages()
    setChats(chats.data.data)
  }

  const handleReceiveMessage=(message)=>
  {
    
    let newMessageChatIndex = [...chats].findIndex(chat =>
       {
        
        return chat["chat_id"] == message["chatID"]})

    
    const updatedChats = Object.assign([], chats, {
    [newMessageChatIndex]: {
        chat_id: selectedChatID,
        chat_messages: [...chats[newMessageChatIndex].chat_messages,
        message],
        },
    })
    
    setChats(updatedChats)

    
  }

  useEffect(()=>
  {
    socket.on("receive-message",(message)=>
    {
      handleReceiveMessage(message)
    })

    socket.emit("add-user",{user_email:currUser["_id"]}); 

    return ()=>
    {
      socket.off('receive-message');
    }
  },[])
  
  useEffect(() => {

    getChatsDataFromDB()


  }, [])



  useEffect(() => {
    let currChatIndex = chats.findIndex(chat => chat["chat_id"] == selectedChatID)
    setSelectedChatIndex(currChatIndex)

  }, [selectedChatID, chats])

  const handleSendNewMessage = async (messageText) => {
    let message_id=v4()
    let newMessage=
    {
      _id:message_id,
      to:chats[selectedChatIndex]["partner_id"],
      chatID:selectedChatID,
      userID:currUser["_id"],
      text:messageText,
      sentAt:new Date()
    }
    
    try {

      //Adding message to server
      let resp = await messagesSVR.addMessage(newMessage)

      //Executed if message added properly
      if (resp.status == 200) {

        const updatedChats = Object.assign([], chats, {
          [selectedChatIndex]: {
              chat_id: selectedChatID,
              partner_id:[...chats][selectedChatIndex].partner_id,
              chat_messages: [...chats[selectedChatIndex].chat_messages,
              newMessage],
          },
      })
        setChats(updatedChats)
        socket.emit("send-message",newMessage)
        
      }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

  }
```

When I run the app with two tabs opened in the browser, and send a message from one tab ( tab number 1 for the sake of argument) to tab number 2 using the send-message event,the message is indeed received in tab number 2 through the receive-message event in handleReceiveMessage function, but for some reason the chats state variable value is an empty array ( I can see it when I print console.log(chats)) , though it was previously loaded with chats data from data base.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect seems to be refering to the initial values through `handleReceiveMessage`

```
const handleReceiveMessage = (message) =>
  {
    
    let newMessageChatIndex = [...chats].findIndex(chat =>
       {
        
        return chat["chat_id"] == message["chatID"]})

    
    const updatedChats = Object.assign([], chats, {
    [newMessageChatIndex]: {
        chat_id: selectedChatID,
        chat_messages: [...chats[newMessageChatIndex].chat_messages,
        message],
        },
    })
    
    setChats(updatedChats)

    
  }

const handleReceiveMessageRef = useRef();
//refer to latest version
handleReceiveMessageRef.current = handleReceiveMessage

const currUserRef = useRef();
currUserRef.current = currUser;

  useEffect(()=>
  {
    socket.on("receive-message",(message)=>
    {
      handleReceiveMessageRef.current(message)
    })

    socket.emit("add-user",{user_email:currUserRef.current["_id"]}); 

    return ()=>
    {
      socket.off('receive-message');
    }

  },[])
```

The problem you are facing is related to [referring the latest props](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects#extracting-non-reactive-logic-out-of-effects) in useEffect and [why it happens](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects), it will give you an idea on how to handle such problems

Hope it helps